# How to store information about a file but not the file itself?

Tags: macos, filesystems, large-files

I would like to know if it is possible under MacOS to store "information" about some files, but not the files themselves? In essence, what I would like is to off-load certain large files from many of my projects to external drives/machines, but still retain the ability to get information about those off-loaded files when I look into the project directory for listing and information about its contents. I understand that what I am asking is not supported by the FS by default, but is there any third-party framework under which this is possible?

Comment: You could store the inode number, device number, as well as some other metadata. This information is available in stat via `st_dev` and `st_ino` and should uniquely identify the file.

Comment: What's the `linux` tag doing here, on a question where only a MacOS-centric answer would presumably be accepted?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I added the linux tag because MacOS shares a lot in common with linux. I don't presume that the solution I am looking for would be necessarily MacOS centric.

Comment: @deepak, to be sure, but you're wasting the time of folks who only know linux but not macos, who can't be sure that their solutions will actually work on your desired platform.

Comment: By the way -- do you mean to ask for a third-party framework under which this is possible *to implement* an overlay filesystem (as by writing a bunch of code), or are you asking for a third-party tool that will do this out-of-the-box? The former exists (and actually *is* portable to both Linux and MacOS), but it would be a major development project to leverage same; the latter is explicitly outside StackOverflow's scope/topic (which disallows tool requests, and is also limited to questions about software development).

Comment: A ready made solution would be obviously preferable, but I am not averse to developing something within a reasonable timeframe, but probably am not inclined to undertake a major development. In retrospect I do think that probably my question does not fit here very well, do you think it should be migrated to a more suitable forum?